# activiti-designer-5.18.0 mvn package wrong

Tags: activiti

#### i checked activiti-designer-5.18.0 tag and mvn package wrong,it seems that the http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.11.4. can't found.how can i resolve this.The console is blow:

```html
➜  Activiti-Designer-activiti-designer-5.18.0 mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Computing target platform for MavenProject: org.activiti.designer:org.activiti.designer.libs:5.18.0-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/qk/Downloads/Activiti-Designer-activiti-designer-5.18.0/org.activiti.designer.libs/pom.xml
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201406250900/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201409261001/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201501121000/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Fetching p2.index from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/201502271000/ (0B at 0B/s)
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.11.4
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'Graphiti' from location http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.11.4: No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.11.4. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'Graphiti' from location http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.11.4
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:121)
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of Graphiti used has been archived so you will need to update the location.
This is easy to do by editing the org.activiti.designer.parent pom.xml and changing the graphiti-site to : http://archive.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.11.4

the root pom will now compile.
Hope this helps,
Greg